mongodb atlas configuration with spring data jpa isnt workig
im trying to connect my mongodb atlas with spring with the following.
        <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Data MongoDB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

application.properties
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://username:password@lolsearch.ro9ti.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=lolSearch
it isn't working, when i try to test the connection is like it doesn't read mongodb+ its starting from srv:// but when i force the mongodb+ in the connection test it works. I dont know how to fix it. im using itellij.
I tried to replace the + sign to %2B but it didnt work

Have you tried putting the value between quotation marks, like: spring.data.mongodb.uri="mongodb+srv://username:password@lolsearch.ro9ti.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=lolSearch"
